# autocomplete="current-password" in React not showing fill form

Tags: html, reactjs, autocomplete

I am having an issue while using the `autocomplete="current-password"` where the form is not showing the current password. The password is saved in Chrome. The `input` is wrapped in a `form`. Is anyone having issues with `autocomplete="current-password"` not working for them?

here is my input for React:

```
<input
  type={this.state.visible ? `text` : `password`}
  onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange('password', e.target.value)}
  autoComplete="current-password"
  placeholder="password"
 />
```

I have not seen any reference to this not working or anyone mentioning this not working.

note: `autoComplete` must be spelled this way in React as react does not recognize the attribute as `autocomplete` but renders on the `DOM` as `autocomplete`

here is how the element is rendering on the `DOM`:

```
<form class="sign-in">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="achroma@gmail.com" autocomplete="username" name="email" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="password-top">
      <label>Password</label>
      <span class="password-toggle">show password</span>
    </div>
  <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="password">
  <span class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: do you have autocomplete="username" anywhere around? in parent form may be?

Comment: @SimDim look at the rendering of the DOM I just added

Comment: are you trying this on localhost?

Comment: Watch for the capitalized C in `autoComplete`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your resulting HTML lacks `name="password"` at least.

Also, currently Chrome doesn't suggest password auto-fill for localhost. I had to turn off and turn back on auto-sign-in in Chrome settings, since my Chrome didn't suggest password auto-fills on any sites. Hope it helps.

I've tested your code in a clean react project, just added `name="password"` to the password input, and used a proxy to my machine. It seems to work in Chrome.